# What happened to the Vault under the Jedi Temple after Order 66?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, order-66

I watched this video:

It was about the Vault under the Jedi Temple where the Jedi kept all their credits.

This led me to the following question: **What happened to the Vault and the massive amount of credits inside after Order 66?**

Comment: Republic credits are no good here

Comment: For the record, there's no *canon* confirmation that there's a great big vault under the temple where the Jedi keep all their credits and where Yoda goes to swim like Scrooge McDuck.

Comment: @Valorum I don't care that's now head canon for me

Answer (score 2):

The Jedi Temple, and by extension its various [vaults](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Holocron_Vaults) and [archives](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Archives), came into the possession of the Emperor when he [took it over](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Imperial_Palace) after the fall of the Jedi Order. Anything of value within would have become his personal possession.

Purely for the record, there's no good indication that the Jedi keep their credits under their temple (and why would they, when banking services exist?) and the Jedi only number 10,000 and don't have extensive investment in property or ships, so [their wealth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90561/if-jedi-arent-supposed-to-own-anything-then-where-do-they-get-their-money-from) probably isn't all that impressive compared to the income from a single  planet.

Comment: I think the best way to look at the Jedi is as a police force. The Police in the UK have a budget of £20Bn, but it's not all kept in a big pile of gold under their HQ in London and compared to the budget of the *entire government*, it pales into comparison.